# Should I unittest private/protected method

Tags: python, unit-testing, oop, language-agnostic, private

This is actually language agnostic. But I'll give you context in python.

I have this parent class

```
class Mammal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """ do some work """

    def eat(self, food):
        """Eat the food"""
        way_to_eat = self._eating_method()
        self._consume(food)

    def _eating_method(self):
        """Template method"""

    def _consume(self, food):
        """Template method"""
```

Here `eat` is the only public method whereas `_consume` and `_eating_method` are actually protected methods which will be implemented by child classes.

*What will you test when you have written only the `Mammal` class?*

Obviously all 4 methods.

Now let's introduce a child

```
class Tiger(Mammal):    
    def _eating_method(self):
        """Template method"""

    def _consume(self, food):
        """Template method"""
```

Look at this class. It has only 2 *protected* methods.

*Should I test all 4 methods of `Tiger` (including 2 inherited) or just test the changes introduced (only overrided 2 methods)?*

**What is the ideal case?**

Comment: That depends. Normally, the `eat`-method is tested with every possible outcome of `_eating_method` and `_consume`. So only the changed methods have to be tested.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**From a theoretical point of view**, you only need to test public methods of your instantiable classes (in standard OOP languages). There is no point in testing the internal behaviour because all you want is "which output for that input" (for a particular method, or for the entire class). You should try to respect it as much as you can because it forces you to ask some questions about the [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) of your class and the provided interface which may be decisive for your architecture.

**From a pragmatic point of view**, you can sometimes have some abstract helper classes with no implemented concrete subclass or an abstract class factoring 90+% of its child classes and where it would be too hard to test  the output without plugging into a protected method. In those kinds of cases, you can [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) a subclass.

In your straightforward example, I would suggest you to only test the class `Tiger` (and only the public method `eat`).

> Just a note for people thinking to [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development). In TDD, you shouldn't have started to code the class `Mammal` before the class `Tiger` because `Mammal` should be the result of a refactoring phase. So, you certainly woudn't have any specific test for `Mammal`.

Comment: Yes, you can just test this method (the only one which is public).

Answer (score 5):

The way I would approach this is:

- Create a minimal testable subclass of `Mammal` which provides minimal implementations of the two protected methods that allow you to unit test the behavior of the public methods.
- Write separate unit tests for each subclass which again test the public methods on `Mammal`, but are asserting the behavior that is specific to that subclass.

This should give you the necessary testing coverage with a minimal number of tests.

One alternative approach would be to test the subclasses only, and on one of the subclass unit tests also assert the features specific to `Mammal`. This avoids the need to create a specific testing subclass, however two disadvantages are:

- You are no longer testing `Mammal` in isolation, and therefore the tests on the `Mammal` specific code are susceptible to failing because of issues in the subclass.
- It may be less obvious to others how and where the properties of `Mammal` are being tested.

Answer (score 1):

When testing you should focus on the outside behaviour of your code, not on implementation details. I don't know the context, so I'll just make some huge assumptions here.

Do you really care about the behaviour of a (potentially abstract) Mammal superclass? Is the reuse-through-inheritance relationship that important? What if you decide to replace the inheritance relationship to a composition-based strategy?

I would focus on testing the behaviour of the classes you actually care about: "Does a Tiger eat as expected?" instead of testing some abstract superclass that is only introduced for code reuse.